# Would it be unprofessional to include SAT scores in a graduate application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, exams, international-students

The SAT is what you take for undergrad admissions in the US. But would a near perfect score on my CV help? I'm asking as an international applicant--the reading portion is significantly harder than the TOEFL, and a perfect score on TOEFL is nowhere near a perfect score on the SAT. I also think that a high SAT subject Math level 2 test is a lot more impressive than a high GRE quantatative score.

I was taught that the CV can include whatever it wants, but was also taught to keep it relevant and professional. If I were to include SAT scores, I would place them under the TOEFL and GRE scores and use the title "other standardized tests"; but would this make my application appear less professional?

Comment: The Physics GRE was a lot harder than the Physics AP test (no Physics SAT test per se) back in the day. I would hope that held true for math as well, since the SAT math section didn't even get to calculus. SAT was then, GRE or TOEFL is now, but getting a degree from a US university likely trumps the TOEFL score anyway. Trying to use an SAT score seems like grasping at straws. Perhaps not unprofessional, but unlikely to help much of anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you'd like to use your scores to show English proficiency, my personal preference would be to add it parenthetically in your language section, which would be good information for international applicants to include

Languages:  First language, XXXX; English (proficient: SAT verbal:XXX, TOEFL:ZZZ)    -- or something along these lines.

As for the math scores, I'd say "not so much".  If your portfolio doesn't show proficiency in some other way (e.g., GRE is years later than the SAT, and you've taken a whole bunch of course work after the SAT), that might be enough to put your application in the reject pile for classes of jobs that might care about your math skills.